# Java inheritance, Looping through each subclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm trying to loop through multiple objects of different types that are all extending the same parent class. For example:

```
ArrayList<Enchant> enchants = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside of the enchants array would be objects of classes that extend an `Enchant` class.

For example:

```
public class JumpBoost extends Enchant{
    public static Item generateItem(){
        return something;
    }
}
```

Each object in the enchants ArrayList would have a method called     generateItem().

I would like to loop through it using:

```
for(Enchant enchant : enchants){
    enchant.generateItem()
}
```

I've already tried doing this, but with no luck due to the Enchant class not having the `generateItem()` method.

I essentially just need a way to group and loop through multiple objects of different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **polymorphism** to solve that problem.
First define the base class/abstract class/interface with the method generateItem(), derive specified classes and override/implement generateItem() method.
Here is implementation with interface:

```
interface Base{
    void generateItem();
}
class Derived1 implements Base{
    @Override
    public void generateItem() {
        System.out.println("generateItem() from Derived1");
    }
}
class Derived2 implements Base{
    @Override
    public void generateItem() {
        System.out.println("generateItem() from Derived2");
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Base> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Derived1());
        list.add(new Derived2());
        list.forEach(Base::generateItem);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
generateItem() from Derived1
generateItem() from Derived2
```

For more, you can read about polymorphism [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Comment: Shouldn't the second output be from Derived2?

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic approach is to define an abstract `generateItem()` on `Enchant`. If you can't modify `Enchant` for some reason, you could create an abstract subclass of `Enchant`, and make all your subclasses inherit from that.

You could also try making an interface with `generateItem()` that all the subclasses implement and store the Interface type in the `ArrayList`.

If you still can't do any of those for whatever reason, you should rethink your design. But as a last resort, you can use reflection to dynamically access the `generateItem` of each individual subclass. Just call `.getClass()` and then lookup the method and invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Give `Enchant` an abstract method that subclasses need to implement. Making it abstract means `Enchant` doesn't need a definition of the method, but subclasses do.

```
public class Enchant {
    public abstract Item generateItem();
}
```

The method should not be a `static` method as you have it in your code. It should be an instance method, since you're calling it on instances of `Enchant`.

Answer (score -1):

Make enchant as interface or abstract class and extend it in the derived classes